# Text taking up no space

Tags: spacing

I want to typeset some text while LaTeX ignores the space that the text will take. In the MWE below using a zero-sized picture accomplishes that while using a `\raisebox` does not.

```
 % nospacetextprob.tex
\documentclass{report} % but could be book, article, etc
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\shiftpic}{\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(0,-1.1\textheight){\textbf{shiftpic}}\end{picture}}
\newcommand{\shifttext}{\raisebox{-1.1\textheight}{\textbf{shifttext}}}

\begin{document}
\shiftpic 
%  \hspace{6em} \shifttext
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Both `\shiftpic` and `\shifttext` are meant to put their argument below the `\textheight`. `\shiftpic` works well but `\shifttext` adds a couple of pages to the document.

I have vague memories of some TeX code that nullifies the vertical space taken up by some text. Call it `\nospace` so `\nospace{\shiftit}` would work like `\shiftpic`. Can someone please remind me of it?

Comment: Maybe you're alluding to `\rlap` (or `\llap` or even `clap`)?

Comment: you are missing the optional arguments of \raisebox, and naturally it also has a width.

Comment: @Bernard since `\clap` isn't in the kernel, I'd rather suggest `\makebox[0pt][c]{<stuff>}` here.

Comment: Plus `\smash` for vertically taking no space.

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz: It' not in the kernel, but it's in mathtools, that almost  everyone should load for the layout of formulæ. This being said, it depends on the context. There are also 6 similar commands that come with `stackengine`: `\tllap,\trlap,\tclap,\bllap,\brlap`and `\bclap`.

Comment: Another suggestion: Why not use `eso-pic`?

Comment: @Bernard just wanted to suggest `eso-pic` as well. Or the dev-kernel and `\AddToHook{shipout/background}{<stuff>}` (which is roughly the same as using `eso-pic`)

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz `\smash` was what I couldn't remember for vertically taking no space (I've slightly edited my question to make that clearer). Would you like to turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You have to nullify the height and depth, but also the width.

```latex
\documentclass{report} % but could be book, article, etc
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\shiftpic}{\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(0,-1.1\textheight){\textbf{shiftpic}}\end{picture}}
\newcommand{\shifttext}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{-1.2\textheight}[0pt][0pt]{\textbf{shifttext}}}}

\begin{document}
\shiftpic\shifttext
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]